# Using multiple Mat progress bar in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat progress bar in image slider,

> app.module.ts

```
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
```

> component.html

```
 <div>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let img of lists; let i = index">
 <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="determinateCnt"></mat-progress-bar>
 </div>
```

> component.ts

```
  startCounter() {
    setInterval(() => {
       this.determinateCnt += 3;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Issue is if i go to second slide after clicking on next button then also i can see that progressbar running which was initiated in the first slide and second slide.

Note: In my for loop there will only be one element at any given time.

Any solution to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: When will you want to show progress bar ?

Comment: You should assign a field to return of the setInterval method and call clearInterval on ngDestroy

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I want to reset progress bar when I go to next slide

Comment: @user3653474 reset means ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda presently in my case when I move to next slide then also progress bar is running that I initiated in the previous slide but I want if progress bar is initiated on first slide then it should be shown on first slide but not on second slide

Comment: @user3653474 Did you still facing this issue ?